# If 2020 Were A Sudoku

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

A bit of light relief to round out the year. No special genius required :-)

[image]

Comment: i suggest u crop the initial screenshot more so that it would look much better :0

Comment: well this is 2020 after all, so it's supposed to look bad ;-)

Comment: ... how is that even a sudoku!

Comment: I would definitely take oAlt's advice to crop it. It looks a bit sloppy especially because cropping it doesn't take that much work.

Comment: ^^^ if you really want to convey the idea of 2020 being bad, you can make it look bad in other ways apart from not cropping (e.g. make the font in the sudoku comic sans :P )

Comment: @oAlt was correct, dammit - Comic Sans font would have been much more appropriate for this puzzle :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reasoning:

> First notice that the given grid has 81 squares, and that the squares seem to be in the correct order, just cut off at seven columns. Realigning gives:
>
>  [image: Grid 1]

From here:

> Standard sudoku reasoning quickly gets us to:
>
>  [image: Grid 2]

Next steps:

> Noting that the right column of the bottom left box has to be 1, 6, and 7, we can place the entire column, which lets us fix all the 1s in the grid. This forces the 3 in the lower left square of the middle box, which forces an 8 in the middle left square of the bottom middle box. The contents of the bottom boxes are all forced with standard Sudoku reasoning at this point. The grid thus far:
>
>  [image: Grid 3]

Moving on:

> The 8 in the 5th column must be in the middle box, and is in fact forced into the top square, allowing us to finish all of the 8s. We can now place the 6 and 9 in the 6th column, which forces the remaining two squares in the 6th column, middle box to be 2 and 7. This forces the two squares in the 5th column, middle box to be 5 and 6, which gives a 7 in R1C5. Most of the rest of the grid then falls easily, getting us to:
>
>  [image: Grid 4]

At this point:

> I think there's something I'm missing, because this has two solutions...any one of the squares remaining can be either 2 or 7, forcing all the others around. Maybe this is part of 2020 being a Sudoku?

Comment: As Jeremy Dover correctly surmised, rot13(Gur snpg gurer ner gjb fbyhgvbaf vf vaqrrq cneg bs 2020 orvat n Fhqbxh)

Comment: Haha, I love this puzzle more than I thought I would now I've seen this ending! Here's hoping 2020 ends in a similarly smile-raising fashion...

Comment: @Stiv It's kinda neat in hindsight, but I admit I wasn't too happy with happystar at 2 in the morning :-)